# How to form This JSON from this Javascript array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapping

I have this JavaScript array of arrays

```
   arr1= [ 
       ['a', 'b'],
       ['1', '2']
       ]
```

And I need to form this JSON object

```
[
    {
        "label":"a",
        "value":"1"
    },
    {
        "label":"b",
        "value":"2"
    },
]
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Do you think this is clearer? Where's _your code_?

Comment: Someone answered your last question already 2 hours ago.

Comment: And if they complain that the question isn't clear, you should edit the question, not post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = [ ['a', 'b'], ['1', '2'] ];

const [labels, values] = arr;
const res = labels.map((label, index) => ({ label, value: values[index] }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Please don't answer low-quality questions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this ...

```js
const entries = new Map([
  ['foo', 'bar'],
  ['baz', 42]
]);

const obj = Object.fromEntries(entries);

console.log(obj);
// expected output: Object { foo: "bar", baz: 42 }
```

Did you mean something like this?
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array with the keys of the wanted objects and reduce and map the items.

```js
const
    data = [['a', 'b'], ['1', '2']],
    keys = ['label', 'id'],
    result = data.reduce((r, a, i) => a.map((v, j) => ({ ...r[j], [keys[i]]: v })), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71802119/how-to-this-json-from-this-javascript-array-of-arrays/71802148#comment126886342_71802148 x 14